# Simpletest on select field loaded by ajax

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, testing

I have searched through Google and haven't found an answer. Stack Exchange is my last resort.

In my form, I have two select fields:

```
$form['system']['foo'] = array(
  ...
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array('A', 'B', 'C'),
  ...
  '#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'change',
    ...
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);

$form['system']['bar'] = array(
  ...
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(),
  '#prefix' => ...
  '#suffix' => ...
);
```

If user selects any of the options in `foo` field, the `bar` field dynamically loads the options through ajax. Example: If 'A' is selected on `foo`, `bar` field generates options like 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' and can be selected by the user.

This form works and I need to provide its unit test using 'Simpletest'.

On my test case:

```
$edit = array(
  'system[foo]' => 1, // value for 'A'
  'system[bar]' => 2, // value for 'bbb'
);
$this->drupalPost('mymodule/mypath', $edit, t('Submit'));
```

gives an error saying `system[bar]` cannot be set to 2 (because it has no value of 2 yet?)

I need to emulate ajax call on `system[foo]` before setting `system[bar]`.

I have tried `drupalPostAjax`:

```
$edit = array(
  'system[foo]' => 1, // value for A
);
$this->drupalPostAjax('mymodule/mypath', $edit, 'system[foo]');
```

and gives me a success result on ajax. On the next lines of code, I tried calling `drupalPost()` again using the previous code snippet but gives me the same error saying `system[bar]` cannot be set to 2.

How can I solve my problem? Please provide sample code as it can help me a lot..

---

EDIT:

Ajax works on the actual page (i.e the values are dynamically loaded to `system['bar']`). So I can assume my code in the forms is working.

However, I just noticed that ajax does not work on the generated page from Simpletest (the one found in **sites/default/files/simpletest/verbose**). Console from Google Chrome does not show any errors. Ajax returns status 200 but does not have any response.

I am using the default theme upon installation.

---

EDIT: The form and simpletest code

The form: I copied the form posted by znerol.

The simpletest code:

```
class MyModuleTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {
  protected $admin_user;

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
      'name' => 'Test Case name',
      'description' => 'Test Case Description',
      'group' => 'My Module',
    );
  }

  public function setUp() {
    // Enable module
    parent::setUp(array('mymodule'));

    // Get permissions
    $permissions = mymodule_get_permissions();
    // Permissions obtained correctly.

    // Create and login admin user
    $this->admin_user = $this->drupalCreateUser($permissions);
    $this->drupalLogin($this->admin_user);
  }

  // Test section
  public function testSystem() {
    $this->drupalGet('mymodule/mypath');
    $edit = array(
      'system[foo]' => 1, // Selects 'A'. Tested!
    );
    $this->drupalPostAjax(NULL, $edit, 'system[foo]');
    // Bar after ajax is loaded
    $edit = array(
      'system[bar]' => 1, // Selects 'aaa'
    );
    $this->drupalPost(NULL, $edit, t('Submit')); // Error here.
    $this->assertText(t('Submitted!'));
  }
}
```

However, when running simpletest, simpletest complains that `system['bar']` cannot be set to `1` (aaa).

I have noticed simpletest shows the following warning before it calls ajax.

> Undefined offset: 0 Notice drupal_web_test_case.php 2147 DrupalWebTestCase >drupalPostAJAX()
>
> Undefined index: Notice drupal_web_test_case.php 2148 DrupalWebTestCase->drupalPostAJAX()
>
> Undefined index: #ajax Notice ajax.inc 379 ajax_form_callback()

Since `system['bar']` is loaded dynamically through ajax, it has an empty array initially `array()`. From the warning above, I tried adding a temporary option `array('1', '2')` in `system['bar']`. The same error and warning occurs.

Comment: Regarding "Undefined index: #ajax": It looks like the #ajax-array is missing on `$form['system']['foo']`.

Comment: @znerol, Do I have to add `$form['system']['foor']['#ajax-array']` explicitly? Tried that too. Didn't work. I'm actually stuck. :D

Comment: No, I suppose that you perhaps missed the stuff in `#ajax` when copying my code of the `$form['system']['foo']` element. Please double check your form implementation and compare it line by line with mine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did. This is just a simple mouse select, copy, and paste of the function contents. I have verified, my form works, but fails on simpletest.

Comment: OK, its the permissions then. Review your simpletest log, I bet you'll find an entry along the lines _mymodule/mypath returned 403_

Comment: Sorry but there are no 403 messages. I have enabled all permissions in `mymodule` in simpletest. I have already verified this.

Comment: Ok, then please verify that `$this->drupalGet()` is actually operating on the correct path (look for 404). Over here my module combined with your test runs smooth. If you cannot find the problem, then please post the whole test-log. Run simpletest from the command line to optain a text-log, e.g.: `php scripts/run-tests.sh --verbose --url http://localhost/ --class MyModuleTestCase`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `$path` parameter to `NULL` when submitting to the same form. Otherwise drupalPost / drupalPostAJAX will first retrieve the page again, and thus generating a new form instead of rebuilding the current one.

The following test should do what you want:

```
// First retrieve the page once
$this->drupalGet('mymodule/mypath');

// Set $path to NULL on subsequent requests to the same form
$edit = array('system[foo]' => 1);
$this->drupalPostAJAX(NULL, $edit, 'system[foo]');

$edit = array('system[bar]' => 2);
$this->drupalPost(NULL, $edit, t('Submit'));
```

The test case succeeds when performed on the following form:

```
function mymodule_myform($form, &$form_state) {
  $foo_options = array('A', 'B', 'C');
  $foo_default = isset($form_state['values']['system']['foo']) ? $form_state['values']['system']['foo'] : NULL;

  $form['system']['#tree'] = TRUE;

  $form['system']['foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $foo_options,
    '#default_value' => $foo_default,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_myform_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'bar-div',
      'method' => 'replace',
    ),
  );

  $bar_choices = array(
    0 => array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
    1 => array('ddd', 'eee', 'fff'),
    2 => array('ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
  );
  $form['system']['bar'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="bar-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => isset($bar_choices[$foo_default]) ? $bar_choices[$foo_default] : array(),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_myform_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['system']['bar'];
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It says **Failed to set field `system[bar]` to 2**. Does this work in your own copy?

Comment: Yes it does. Pay extra attention when passing arrays with number-keys to `#options`. The index 2 points to the third element.

Comment: Ajax works on the actual page (i.e the values are dynamically loaded to system['bar']). So I can assume my code in the forms is working.

However, I just noticed that ajax does not work on the generated page from Simpletest (the one found in sites/default/files/simpletest/verbose). Console from Google Chrome does not show any errors. Ajax returns status 200 but does not have any response.

I am using the default theme upon installation.

Comment: It is normal that Ajax does not work on the pages linked from the simpletest log. Ajax forms rely on the form cache and that is only valid in the simpletest child site during the execution of the test case.

Comment: It would help if you could update your post with a minimal but complete example of the form which actually works together with an exact test case which fails.

Comment: Edited my post containing the form and the test case.

Comment: Regrettably the form implementation is incorrect. Because the logic for populating the bar-options-field is in the Ajax callback, users having JavaScript disabled will not be able to submit it (test it yourself by disabling JavaScript in your browser). Do you have the option to fix the form or are you forced to implement a test for exactly this broken implementation?

Comment: I now follow how you implemented the form. The form is still working, but simple test shows the same error. It cannot set `system['bar']` to `1`. I have noticed it shows several warnings before calling ajax in simpletest. Please see edits.

Comment: Awarded you the bounty for your great effort in helping me solve the problem. I am still in the process of fixing these based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have noticed in your following code:

```
$form['system']['foo'] = array(
  ...
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array('A', 'B', 'C'),
  ...
  '#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'change',
    ...
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);

$form['system']['bar'] = array(
  ...
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(),
  '#prefix' => ...
  '#suffix' => ...
);
```

the `system[bar]` fields has been initialized with an empty array: array().

And than you are trying to set the value of that field that doesn't contains any option. My guess is can you initialize the options for `system[bar]` fields as well. I know you have mentioned that the `bar` field dynamically loads the options through ajax. But I think the value on that field cannot be set unless it is initialized with proper set of result.

Comment: There is no problem with the form. The problem is how to simulate ajax dynamically loaded select on `$form['system']['bar']` before submitting the form.